# Google Calendar API: Generate Google Meet Link for non-workspace account users?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

After solving [the general issue of creating a Google Meet Event + Link programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916295/google-calendar-api-create-event-google-meet-link?noredirect=1#comment133925809_75916295), even given the many questions regarding issues of this procedure, I'm facing my next question regarding the Google API.

Please note that I'm asking this question on SO and not on any of Google's Support Channels, as Google themselves recommend people [to use SO for technical support](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support#questions_advice).

So let's say you have managed to create a Google Calendar Event + a related Google Meet Link programmatically, via the approach in my linked answer above. Let's then say you have a Google Workspace Account user, called (A). Then you have two random persons living on planet earth, called (B) and (C). (B) and (C) DO NOT have a Google Account.

Can I use the Google Workspace Account user (A) to programmatically generate a Google Meet Link for a call held among (B) and (C) (WITHOUT (A), and WITHOUT (A) needing to allow access for (B) or (C) to join the Google Meet session) ?

The reason I'm asking is because we're trying to build the following software implementation:

- You're the owner of the Company A
- Company A has a Google Workspace Account
- Using the linked procedure, you're able to generate Google Events + Google Meet Links with another person B who wants to schedule an interview with the owner of the company A (1:1 sessions). This works, as one of the members participating in the Google Meet Call is the owner of the Google Workspace Account.
- What we're now looking for is: Could we use the Google Workspace Account from A to programmatically generate a Google Meet Call which can be used by B and another person C in a call among B and C, exclusively among B and C, without A needing to provide any access at the moment B or C click on the link? And without any of B or C needing to have a Google Account?

Comment: if you create a event under A's calendar and then invite b, c, and d they should all see the meeting link.    I recommend you test it

Comment: We've tested this and the generation of the links etc. all works. But if b, c and / or d click on the Google Meet Link, they can only join the session after A allows them to do so in Google Meet, which is not possible if A is not supposed to be part of the session. Our goal would be that b c and / or d can use the Google Meet Links generated via A's workspace account to hold inividual meetings among themselves, without needing A's access approval at the moment they join.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo and btw, is it actually even possible to be running multiple Google Meet sessios (e.g. one among b and c, and another one among d and e, both running at the same time), if the according Google Meet Links have been generated with the same workspace account?

Comment: And if so, is there a limit on the amount of such concurrent sessions? Time limit seems to be 60 minutes?

Comment: I don't think there is any way too get around the fact that the owner of the event needs a approved people from outside the domain joining

Comment: @DevelJoe if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76036353/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: The answer you refer to talks about something different hence it was neither bad nor particularly helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a Google Meet from a Google Workspace that allows external members without Google accounts into the meeting for security reasons to prevent unwanted participants into the meeting.

You can use the Quick Access feature from Google Meet for participants to join without having to request it, but that access would just be temporary and they still require a Google account for that since it is the only way for Google to recognize that they have been invited to the meeting:

> For meetings created from Google Calendar, invited participants can join anytime between 15 minutes before the scheduled time and the end of the meeting. Otherwise, participants will need to knock to join the meeting.

I think in this case Google Meet may not be the best solution for you in terms of meeting features. You could still use Google Calendar with something like Zoom for example, or maybe add a URL or instructions on how to join a different service for meetings in the event description.

More info about this same behavior can be found in Google's Issue Tracker below.

#### References:

- [Quick Access](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9303164?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:%7E:text=Control%20access%20to%20a%20video%20meeting%20with%20Quick%20access)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/166749877)