# Google workspace shows: Not Found 404

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I am using [google workspace](https://admin.google.com/) to mange my calanders:

And I have this code to try and access it:

```
    $calendar_id = "***********@resource.calendar.google.com";
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/google-calendar/service-account-credentials.json'));
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

    // list all events
    $service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendar_id);

    return $results;
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
"{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"notFound\",\n    \"message\": \"Not Found\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 404,\n  \"message\": \"Not Found\"\n }\n}\n"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's missing here is the calendar that is supposed to be accessed, you can add the line below to achieve this (The line was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75931397/17987690), there is also a lot more code there but the line below is the only thing missing from your code)

```php
$client->setSubject(
            subject: "Here, you have to enter your Google Workspace Account Username"
        );
```

The reason why you get the "Not found" error message is because the service account itself was trying to show it's own calendar however service accounts do not have a calendar to show and that's why you don't get any other type of error message.

Hope this helps!